# Angular 2 service data can't assign to variable in constructor

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular 2 application's constructor i need to assign service function returning data to a public variable and show in html view. Console log works well but html data not showing. So i'm assuming data is not assigning to the variable. Following is my code snippet.

```js
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  public listname ="Laravel list";

  constructor(private laraveldataservice: LaravelDataServiceService) { }

  public dataList = this.laraveldataservice.getUsers();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.laraveldataservice.getUsers();
  }

}
```

Basically ng oninit data is loading in console log. But dataList value is not assigning.

Service code,

```js
getUsers(){
    const url = 'http://localhost/laravel_app/public/api/users';
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(
      res => {
        const data = res.json();
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you post code for `laraveldataservice.getUsers()`?

Comment: It works well. Since console log values are assigning properly. Anyhow i have updated the question with the code.

Comment: Are you doing `*ngFor` on your `dataList` in your html page?

Answer (score 1):

Your `console.log` works because it fires in your `Rx` subscription. Your `dataList` never gets populated with anything due to the `async` nature of the call. What I do in my code is to convert it to a `promise` and then `await` it.

Example:

```
async ngOninit() {
 this.dataList =  await this._httpClient
  .get<TData>(url)
  .toPromise();
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by withCredentials?

Comment: Ignore withcredentials, just copied it from my code, I use it

Answer (score 0):

Place it inside ngOnit and declare variable outside

```
 public dataList : any;

 ngOnInit() {
   this.dataList  = this.laraveldataservice.getUsers();
  }
```

Comment: Not working. I declared public dataList; and inside ngOnInit did as you have mentioned.

Comment: it should check the answer above

Comment: how do you say its not assigning

Comment: In html i'm accessing the assigned value like this.  {{ dataList }} But it's not showing nothing. But in the console log shows the data.

Comment: try {{ dataList |json }} and see what is the output

Comment: strange , can you post whole of your component code right now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162857/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-codecanyon).

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

**Service**

```
private defaultDataSub = new Subject<any>();
onDefalultDataLoad = this.defaultDataSub.asObservable();

getUsers(){
    const url = 'http://localhost/laravel_app/public/api/users';
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(
      res => {
        const data = res.json();
        this.defaultDataSub.next(data);
      }
    );
  }
```

**Component**

```
import {Subscription} from "rxjs";

export class ListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

public listname ="Laravel list";

constructor(private laraveldataservice: LaravelDataServiceService) { }

public dataList;

public subscription:Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.laraveldataservice.onDefalultDataLoad.subscribe(data => {
  this.dataList = data;
  });
}
ngOnDestroy(){
 this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
}
```

> You are setting `dataList` property before data coming from server. May be this is the reason for your problem

Comment: I hope this will work. Try this and let me know the result

Comment: Share a stackblitz for your problem

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is :

```js
getUsers(){
    const url = 'http://localhost/laravel_app/public/api/users';
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(map(res => res.json()))
}
```

And in your component.ts file :

```js
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  public listname ="Laravel list";

  constructor(private laraveldataservice: LaravelDataServiceService) { }

  public dataList ;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.laraveldataservice.getUsers().subscribe(res => {
      this.dataList = res
  }

}
```